# DateTime not adding time - Strange issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Having this line of code:

```
DateTime inFutureDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60);
```

And writing in the (Unity) console like this

```
Debug.Log("In future date time " + inFutureDateTime.Date)
```

outputs:

```
12/15/2021 12:00:00 AM
```

The Date is correct (today), but the time isn't. It should be CurrentTime + 60 seconds.

What am I doing wrong, or did I misunderstand how the DateTime works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The expression `inFutureDateTime.Date` will *always* return a `DateTime` at midnight. If you want the time part, don't use `.Date`...

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=net-6.0 "A new object with the same date as this instance, and the time value set to 12:00:00 midnight (00:00:00)."

Comment: `Debug.Log($"In future date time {inFutureDateTime:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Date` is a holder intended for Date only.

Unfortunately when converted to string it displays a time component as well.

The default ToString, or one of it's overrides will display the full date time:

```
Debug.Log("In future date time " + inFutureDateTime)
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `.Date`, try calling `.ToLongDateString()` as in `Debug.Log("In future date time "+inFutureDateTime.ToLongDateString())`

Answer (score 0):

Date return component date not date format standard. Please see following approach:

```cs
DateTime inFutureDateTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60); 

Debug.Log("In future date time " + inFutureDateTime.Date.ToLongDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

The origin of the problem is in the `.Date`: it returns *Date* part of the initial `DateTime` value
(note, that *time part* is `0:0:0.000`). I suggest using *string interpolation* where you can specify
text, variables, their formats, etc.

```
 // Here we specify the required format - MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss
 Debug.Log($"In future date time {inFutureDateTime:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss}");
```

If you want to use the default format (from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture`):

```
 Debug.Log($"In future date time {inFutureDateTime}");
```